# Reset form to empty values

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

new to redux-form... I was looking at an example from redux-form docs where one can initialize form values from initialValues (forked example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/6v3n9lwnpr).
Is it possible to have functionality where one can use 'Undo Changes' to reset form to InitialValues, but also have another button to reset to empty form?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the redux-form documentation, you will find what you need under the action creator section. With that, let's answer your questions.

> one can use 'Undo Changes' to reset form to InitialValues

In its documentation, Redux-Form lists out a couple of actions that you can use. You can either use an action creator or used an action that is already bound to the dispatch. For your requirement, you'll need to use the library's `reset` function

a) using action creator

```
import { reset } from 'redux-form';

...// then inside a function you can dispatch the reset action.
resetMyForm() {
 const action = reset('myFormName');
 dispatch(action);
}
```

b) using an action already bound to the dispatch

I wont type this since there is an example in the library on GitHub [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/examples/simple/src/SimpleForm.js)

And as for

> button to reset to empty form

similar to the initial answer but you would have to use the `clearFields` function instead.

Hope this helps.